# Switch Using PMOS transistor

Tags: mosfet, switches, pmos

People, I have very basic question on 'How to make a switch using a PMOS' transistor.

Following are the specifications:
Drain - Output Pin
Source - 4.2V (From Lithium-ion Battery)
Gate - 3.3V / OV (Control Pin)

I am using NDS8434 PMOS. Gate threshold for this is less than -1V.

Question: 
Ideally, if I am connecting Gate to 3.3V then PMOS should be OFF and when I am connecting 0V then PMOS should be ON, But this is not the case?

Comment: Following the product's datasheet the minimum gate threshold voltage is reported on -0.4V at room temperature. The max is -1V. So, no with 0V on the gate you can't turn it on. You need at least -0.4V on the gate-source.

Comment: @dirac16 What about turning it OFF? I think, 3.3V at Gate should turn it off, right?

Comment: You don't need only a 3.3V on the gate to turn it off. Any positive voltage such as 0V or greater should do it.

Comment: If your source is at 4.2V no it will not turn off. You still have -0.9V as your g-s voltage.

Comment: Sorry, I answered in general. In that case, as @RoyC explained it's the voltage on the gate-source that determines if it's on or off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to level shift your 3.3V to 4.2V to use  a pmos device use a circuit like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8xVE6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note The polarity of the input is changed the pmos transistor will be on when the input is high.